# A squad of 4n men form fours. Find the chance that two specified men are next one another in the same four.

Tags: probability

A squad of $4n$ men form fours. Find the chance that two specified men are next one another in the same four.

My working: I understood that we need to divide them in size of 4 and in each of 4 we need to maintain order.

$=\frac{{{4n-2}\choose{2}}\times 3!\times 2!
\times \frac{(4n-4)!}{(n-1)!}}{\frac{4n!}{n!}}=\frac{3}{2(4n-1)}$

But answer given in the book is $\frac {1}{2n}$

Comment: Are they in a row one behind the other?? What does squad mean here? When are two people said to be "next one another in the same four"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that each "four" is to be arranged in a line; otherwise I don't know what "next one another" would mean. I don't follow your work, but I get the same answer.

Let's say you and I are the two specified men. I am assigned to some four; it doesn't matter which, one is as good as another. Of the remaining $4n-1$ men, $3$ will be assigned to my four; so the probability that you will be in my four is $\frac3{4n-1}.$ Now, given that we are in the same four, the probability that we are next to each other is $\frac3{\binom42}=\frac12,$ so the final answer is $\frac3{2(4n-1)}.$

Comment: You are right, but explanation could be better.

Answer (score 0):

First we can analyze the number of configurations they end up in same group at all. Let first person be assigned to any group and only focus on placing the second person. There are 3 spots left in same group and $4n-1$ spots left in total so we have $3/(4n-1)$ that they are in same group. If they are in same group, then if we list the allowed group configurations:
$$ab**\\**ab\\ a**b\\ba**\\ **ba\\ b**a$$

This is $6$ out of $4! = 4\times 3\times 2\times1 = 24$ but you need to consider that the two $**$ can be permuted also, which double the number. Therefore $\frac{12}{24}$ once we know they are in same group.

So in other words $\frac 3 {4n-1} \times \frac {2\times 6}{24} = \frac 3 {2(4n-1)}$

Comment: What makes you think the probability is $1/n$ that they are in the same group? Consider the case $n=2.$ There are $\binom82=28$ pairs of men, and only $2\binom42=12$ pairs that are in the same group of $4$, so in this case the probability is $12/28\lt1/2.$

Comment: @bof First place the first one can be placed in any group without loss of generality and there are 3 spots left in same group and 4n-1 in total. Yep you are right.

Comment: My answer mutated and did not write what i typed.